# ionic cordova build android failed because of adding "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

my App work fine in browser except google maps and it’s because of running
an browser, when I try to execute

```
ionic cordova run android
```

there are some errors, I googled for a few days but unfortunately have no
result to solve my issue.

Here are some results:

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
[Fatal Error] tbxml-android-.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.
[Fatal Error] play-services-maps-11.8.0.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.
[Fatal Error] play-services-location-11.8.0.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.
[Fatal Error] support-core-utils-24.1.0.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.
[Fatal Error] tbxml-android-.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.
[Fatal Error] play-services-maps-11.8.0.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.
[Fatal Error] play-services-location-11.8.0.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.
[Fatal Error] support-core-utils-24.1.0.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

In last few days I tried all suggestions, and so forth tried to create again
the project from scratch and added all pages and plugins one by one.
Everything was okay and my app worked fine on browser, emulator and also on
device but as I added cordova-plugin-googlemaps and ionic-native without any
usage code same error has been occured only for emulator and device. that
means when I execute “ionic serve” command, app works as expected.

My env. info are as follows:

```
$ ionic info

cli packages: (C:\Users\shokoienia\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.9.4
    npm               : 4.6.1
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\shokoienia\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

and list of cordova plugins:

```
$ cordova plugin list
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.2.5 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.16 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.2.1 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` does not work with `ionic serve`

Comment: That's wright. but my problem is about 'ionic cordova build android'.

Comment: Check out this thread. https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/2107